# How to prevent model state binding from altering the InputRequest in .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, modelstate

I have a Web API (POST) which accepts the input JSON and does operation over it. Due to model state binding, the request by default getting bound to the request model.

We are facing a scenario where in the received JSON is not as per the expected format. Like we are having additional key-value pairs which we want to identify and notify about it. Due to model state binding I'm not able to find the additional parameters.

I have been trying the below code but I do not get the actual request. Is there a way to get the actual request rather than the overridden request.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    string uri = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
    uri = uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).ToLower();
    if(uri.Contains("xxx"))
    {
        PartnerLoginSchema reqSchema = new PartnerLoginSchema();
        JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(reqSchema.schemaJson);
        var requestInput = actionContext.ActionArguments["requestx"];// receiving overriden request

        string valid = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestInput);
        JObject jsonObj= JObject.Parse(valid);
        bool testcheck = person.IsValid(schema);

    }
}
```

Eg: Expected JSON

```
{
    req1: "asd",
    req2: "wer"
}
```

Input JSON Received:

```
{
    req1:"asdf",
    req2:"werr",
    req3:"unwanted" // this attribute is not required and has to be identified 
}
```

I would want to find the req3 present in the JSON by some means.

Is there a way to achieve it in ASP.NET C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to achieve it by reading the input JSON from  HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                    settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
                    string req_txt;
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
                    {
                        req_txt = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        ExpectedJsonFormat s =
                            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpectedJsonFormat>(req_txt,
                                settings); // throws expection when over-posting occurs
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, BadAndUnAuthorisedRequest("extra column"));
                    }
```